# Select directory path in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to select a directory via JavaScript?

Not for uploading a file, just to choose a directory path. (Directory dialog or something)

Comment: On the client-side in a web browser?

Comment: Yes. On the client-side.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, for security reasons (you don't want a website to be able to know about your file system).

See below, when you get the value of a file input, it will be mangled (on my computer, for example it will always be `c:/fakepath/something`). The file input also has problems for your usecase : selecting a folder will give you the list of its contents, so an empty folder will log nothing in my snippet.

```js
function browseResult(e){
  var fileselector = document.getElementById('fileselector');
  console.log(fileselector.value);
}
```

```html
<input id="fileselector" type="file" onchange="browseResult(event)" webkitdirectory directory multiple="false" style="display:none" />
<button onclick="getElementById('fileselector').click()">browse</button>
```

You could do it via a plugin, such as Flash, Java or Air for example, but users would have to either have it installed already or install it. The plugin ecosystem seems pretty much dead.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want my app to choose a file. Just to choose in some way a folder path, not a file

Comment: I understand but I don't think it is possible. Not in javascript, anyway. You could have them type the path in a textfield, but that's not as convenient.

Comment: Isn't it possible to select a directory using [`window.showDirectoryPicker()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/showDirectoryPicker)?

Comment: @AndersonGreen that wasn't an option in 2017 ^^. It's still experimental today BTW. I agree that it can work on some usecases (OP never fully explained what they needed)

Answer (score -1):

you cannot get path directly, best you find online to reach to path:

```
$('#fileUploadControl').on('change',function ()
        {
            var filePath = $(this).val();
            console.log(filePath);
        });
```

It will give you **blank** in Firefox and **'Fakepath/..'** in chrome. (Not have tested in IE but of course won't help you.)

Comment: Thanks. I don't want my app to choose a file. Just to choose in some way a folder path, not a file.